# Delete a pointer c++

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a c++ program that in a part of it the size of pointer is increased if user enters more elements. This pointer has a type associated with structure **Entry** and the function that increases the pointer size is

```
Entry *size_increase(Entry *neuu, int *size){
   *size = *size+10;
   Entry *new_neu = new Entry[*size];
   for (int i=0; i<*size; ++i) {
       new_neu[i]=neuu[i];
   }

   return new_neu;
}
```

The pointer **neuu** is the pointer to be increased and the **size** is its initial size. At the end of this function I would like to **delete** the input pointer, **neuu**, to free the memory.

**Problem is:** if I have this sequence

```
delete neuu;
return new_neu;
```

instead of the one that I have in the code above, the compiler stops after taking two user inputs and prints the error

> error for object 0x1002042b8: pointer being freed was not allocated

How can I delete the pointer then?

Edit: Some users are asking about how initially neuu is allocated. Initially I have

```
Entry *neu = new Entry[1];
```

and whenever the user tries to input the second item a function is called as

```
   neu = size_increase(neu,size);
```

Both of these two happen inside the main function.

Comment: We can't see the code that allocates memory for `neuu`. I'm guessing it never gets allocated. Can you show the code that calls `size_increase`?

Comment: You should use `delete[]` for arrays.

Comment: Avoid `new` when possible, use `std::vector` instead

Comment: But if it did not allocate any memory to neuu then it would not run. Without delete the code runs perfectly. I wanted to mention the code here but was afraid it cluttered the page.

Comment: @JameyD You are right. Thanks. Consider adding your reply as answer :)

Comment: I suspect that `neuu` has size original `*size`, and so you have out of bound access in your loop.

Comment: @Gernot1976 Thanks. I am new to c++ and still don't know many of those cool bypasses. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: You increase `size` by 10, and *then* copy from `neuu` to `new_neu`, so you're probably also copying from beyond the end of `neuu`.

Comment: Not considering more modern approaches, you have to ensure that every call to new (new[]) is exactly pared with one (and only one) call to delete (delete[]).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your `neuu` has been created with `new[]` you should use `delete[]` instead of `delete`.

Comment: We don't know how `neuu` was created.

Comment: @MillieSmith according to the comments and [] operator we do.

Comment: @MillieSmith: Now I added the initialization of neu.

Comment: @AminR. I see that. Thanks.